# How to access String Created in an inner class

Tags: android, inner-classes

I've been doing a lot of research about this and I can't find an answer I can implement...
So I hope one of you can help me :)

Here is my problem: I create the `String` "dispo" in depending on how the switch is set, but I can't use this in my URL below...
(I tried to declare the `String` as `final` but it won't work...

Here is the code:

```
    Switch toto = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toto);
    toto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                String dispo = "yes";
            }else{
                String dispo = "no";
            }

        }
    });
new RequestTask().execute("http:myURL" + dispo);
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: you know scope of [class level variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) ?

Comment: No I don't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help.
I figured-out a way to do what I wanted^^

Here is the code:

```
Switch toto = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toto);
toto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                       boolean isChecked) {}
   });

    //check the current state and call the URL accordingly
    if (toto.isChecked()) {
        new RequestTask().execute("http:myURL/script.php&dispo=yes");
    } else {
        new RequestTask().execute("http:myURL/script.php&dispo=no");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `new RequestTask().execute("http:myURL" + dispo);`inside the `onCheckedChanged` method.

Comment: I tried but it gets called only when the switch is activated. And I need to be able to call that URL at any time...

Comment: Had you move inside the if statement also?

Comment: No I had not, when I replied to you, but I did afterwards, thanks a lot!

Comment: And I'll +1 your answer once I have enough reputation^^

Answer (score 0):

Just create the the String 'dispo' before the listener. In your solution the String 'dispo' is only known/valid in the if/else statement (within the braces).

```
String dispo = null;
toto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            dispo = "yes";
        } else {
            dispo = "no";
        }
    }
});

new RequestTask().execute("http:myURL" + dispo);
```